# The import org.springframework.boot.ssl cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, pem

I am using spring boot version 2.7.12. In order to use ssl bundles to have a safe client server connection I am using this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.ssl.SslBundles;


 private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public DisbursementController(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, SslBundles 
sslBundles) {
    this.restTemplate = 
restTemplateBuilder.setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("mybundle")).build();
}
```

**My application.properteis file:**

```
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.mybundle.keystore.certificate=classpath:client_cert.crt
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.mybundle.keystore.private-key=classpath:private.key
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.mybundle.keystore.private-key-passphrase=my_pass
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.mybundle.truststore.certificate=classpath:server_cert.crt
```

**NOTE: Certificates are in PEM format.**

**Showing ERROR:** The import org.springframework.boot.ssl cannot be resolved

Answer (score -1):

This type of error usually occurs with dependency problems in the project.

If you haven't added the dependency and don't know how to do it, visit the [section 4.4 of the official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.first-application.dependencies)  that shows you how to add the 'org.springframework.boot' dependency in both Maven and Gradle.